# Creating lambda expression at runtime

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

How can I create a lambda expression at runtime on a property of type IList

For example, I want Html.EditorFor(model => model.Properties[i])

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorForRepeatGroup<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string PropertyNameToInvoke,int index)
{
    var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
    var item = Expression.Parameter(model.GetType());

    var format = Expression.Constant(index);

    var prop = Expression.Property(item, PropertyNameToInvoke);
    var args = new Expression[] { format,prop };
    //prop.

    Type type = model.GetType();
    //then lambda
    var lambda =  Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel,string>>(prop,item);


    // I want here:
    //System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(htmlHelper, Model => Model.PropertyNameToInvoke[index]);
    System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(htmlHelper, lambda);

    return null;
}
```

This for sure fails.
I am a newbie to expression and exhausted for finding a solution.

Edit:

```
public class GroupViewModel
{
    public GroupViewModel()
    {
        Properties = new List<PropertyRepeatGroup>();

        for (var i = 0; i < this.GetMaxRepeatGroupValueOf(model => model.Properties); i++)
        {
            Properties.Add(new PropertyRepeatGroup());
        }
    }

    [UIHint("PropertyRepeatGroup")]
    [MaximumRepeatGroups(10)]
    public List<PropertyRepeatGroup> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

and
I am intending to use it as:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            <div id="tabBody_@i" class="tabBody">
                Property Id : @i

                @Html.EditorForRepeatGroup(property, i);
               //property here is string representation of class property

            </div>
        }
```

The essence is to make the above view generic so I can call

`Html.MyPartial(model => model.properties)` or

```
Html.MyPartial(otherModel => otherModel.AProperties)
```

and then editor templates for model.properties[x] or otherModel.AProperties[x]

Comment: *Why* does the code that you have fail?

Comment: ParameterExpression of type 'GroupViewModel' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'.. But this is anyway not what I wanted

Comment: you can use [Expression.Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630266(v=vs.110).aspx) like this: `var prop = Expression.Property(item, PropertyNameToInvoke, Expression.Constant(index));` - it equivalent to `item.PropertyNameToInvoke[index]`

Comment: I get this error then : 
Additional information: Instance property 'Properties(Int32)' is not defined for type 'GroupViewModel'

Comment: can you provide your `GroupViewModel` and how you try use `EditorForRepeatGroup`?

Comment: first: why you use `var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;` and then `model.GetType()` instead of simple `typeof(TModel)`, and second: your `Properties` is List of `PropertyRepeatGroup`, so `Properties[i]` have type `PropertyRepeatGroup`, but you try create lambda `Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel,string>>` that should return `string` instead `PropertyRepeatGroup`

Comment: @grundy: Sorry for the language but I have gone mad! Been stuck at this problem for so long, I am trying anything to make it work. 
All I want is model => model.properties to get converted to model=>model.properties[i]

Comment: so, do you can try changes what i say, and show results?

Comment: @grundy: Yes but there are compile time errors. The problem is my generic partial view cannot have a strongly typed model, also I cannot use class PropertyRepeatGroup in the method as it is supposed to be generic for any model class. I have to rethink the approach and come up with a better solution/another approach. I will post again if I get stuck. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Won't the `EditorExtensions.Editor()` method work for you?